# create a visual studio template that includes 3 types of project

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm trying to create a Visual Studio project Template that includes 3 types of projects.

Thus when the user want to create a new project using the template, he should be able to choose first the type of Project.

Is there any method to do this? Or do I have to create a template for each project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [create a multi-project template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185308.aspx), then [create "root wizard"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185301.aspx) which shows some UI to allow project selection, then "child wizard", for each project, which on creating a new project using your template when it's not needed, [throw a `WizardBackoutException`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586502/cancel-vs2010-project-creation-from-wizard) in `RunStarted` method.

But this is sure a bit troublesome. It's much easier to just create a template per project.

Comment: thx for your help :) ! I did exactly what you proposed, but the template is always generating the 3 projects.

Comment: Hmm. That's odd. It worked for me. Try "always throwing" the exception to check conditions. Means, this exactly procedure worked for me. Check out this project for example: https://github.com/nbelyh/VisioPanelAddinVSTO/blob/master/Wizard/ChildWizard.cs

Comment: thx Nikolay ! it works now. Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: No problem. If it works you can mark it as an answer.